# How to get lapply to output 2 objects obtained from a function

Tags: r, function, lapply

I'm trying to lapply a function over a list. Because my function intends to output 2 objects, I'm running into a problem. For each item in the list, running the function only outputs results from the second object.

Here is a vastly simplified example.

```
test<-function(x){
  a<-x+4
  b<-x/34
}
list<-c(3,4,5,6,6)
lapply(list,test)

# Outputs b:
[[1]]
[1] 0.08823529

[[2]]
[1] 0.1176471

[[3]]
[1] 0.1470588

[[4]]
[1] 0.1764706

[[5]]
[1] 0.1764706
```

How to I get the function to output both a and b?

Comment: In your `test` function, add a third line: `return(a = a, b = b)`

Comment: @Benjamin - You mean `return(c(a = a, b = b))` (or `list` depending on preference).  But `return()` is a bit pointless on the last line, just `c(a = a, b = b)` would be fine.

Comment: oops.  I meant to put that in `list`, actually. as in `return(list(a=a, b=b))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function is returning just the last line as it should.
Try:

```
test<-function(x){
a<-x+4
b<-x/34
return(c(a,b))
}
list<-c(3,4,5,6,6)
lapply(list,test)
```